# JAVA - Sending commands to the remote host that uses jump host

Tags: java, ssh

I am searching for a sample code of the SSH connection over the next one.
In general the application needs to login to jump host (over SSH using user, password or the SSH), then it have to login to host2 (over host1) one using the SSH as well.
At the end it need to perform the commands on the host2 and return it back to the application or host1.

How does it possible using JAVA, any suggestions how to handle the SSH jump host solution over SSH?

[image]

Best regards,
WT

Comment: Any suggestions? Anyone? :)

Comment: nice question. Even I'm intrigued to know. Any solution you got for this ?

Comment: @RamPrasadG I think we can use the simple stream to do that, but I would request for the help from someone that already provided the solution, so I know how it might work, but maybe there is different way to handle it.

Comment: so by any chance have you implemented code, if so you can post it as an answer yourself.